# How to cancel a key in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I am working on a MVC project. In my view, there is a jquery dialog, it display a html view with a input box. The input box has onkeypress event function. I tested it in IE, chrome, microsoft edge, opera, the dialog has no problem. But when I tried with Firefox, the the onkeypress always fires with keychar = 99 (which is char c) without I pressing any key. I guess firefox somehow sends a c key.

Is there any way I can cancel the key OUTSIDE the onkeypress? Because c is legal char for the onkeypress.

Thanks

Comment: How can we know if we can't see your "automatically press c" code?

Comment: @Raptor is right. psbookmark please post your code here.